# Converting data stored as a list in each column to longform with column names as variable in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm fairly new to R and it seems this should be simple but my searches are turning up nothing.

I have some data formatted in Excel as a series of lists - ie: row 1 contains categories and the items are listed below like this:

```
   Fruit Vegetable  Grain    Meat
1  Apple    Carrot  Wheat Chicken
2  Grape    Potato   Rice    Beef
3 Banana           Barley    Pork
4 Orange                         
5   Kiwi
```

And I want to turn it into a single long dataframe with the column names becoming categories like this:

```
    Category    Food
1      Fruit   Apple
2      Fruit   Grape
3      Fruit  Banana
4      Fruit  Orange
5      Fruit    Kiwi
6  Vegetable  Carrot
7  Vegetable  Potato
8      Grain   Wheat
9      Grain    Rice
10     Grain  Barley
11      Meat Chicken
12      Meat    Beef
13      Meat    Pork
```

Here is the input data:

```
df <- structure(list(Fruit = c("Apple", "Grape", "Banana", "Orange", 
"Kiwi"), Vegetable = c("Carrot", "Potato", NA, NA, NA), Grain = c("Wheat", 
"Rice", "Barley", NA, NA), Meat = c("Chicken", "Beef", "Pork", 
NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I feel like I should be using tidyr::pivot_longer() but can't quite work out how.

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: You can use `stack` from base R on your data i.e. `stack(df1)[2:1]`

Comment: `pivot_longer(df1, cols = everything(), names_to = "Category", values_to = "Food", values_drop_na = TRUE)` would I think do the job.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you - using pivot_longer() like that did indeed work for me. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add some meat onto the bones of the ideas given in the comments, here is how you would do it:

```
# akrun's answer
option1 <- stack(df)[2:1]
# then we remove the NAs
option1 <- option1[!is.na(option1$values),]
# then rename the columns
colnames(option1) <- c("Category", "Food")

# Paul Stafford Allen's answer
library(tidyverse)

pivot_longer(df, cols = everything(), names_to = "Category", values_to = "Food", values_drop_na = TRUE)
```

I prefer Paul's answer, but both work